# Formula Sequencing Math Problem

Tags: probability

A speaker talked for 60 minutes to a full auditorium.  Thirty percent of the attendees listened to the entire presentation while ten percent slept through the entire talk.  Divide the remaining attendees in half.  The first half is called group A and the second half called group B.

I am given these situations in which I need to find the average number of minutes heard by all members of the audience when Group A has heard 1/3 of them talk and Group B heard 2/3 of them talk.  The average is 30 minutes for all situations given (A: 1/4, B: 3/4, A: 1/5, B: 4/5).  Each time the average comes out to be 30 minutes so I know that is a pattern that has arisen.

I am now supposed to figure out what the average number of minutes heard by the audience if Group A heard one-nth of the lectures and Group B heard the portion of the lecture not heard by Group A? I am confused on how to start this.

Comment: So it looks like you did calculate this for 1/4 vs 3/4 and 1/5 vs 4/5. So, take that same formula and fill in 1/n and (1-1/n) = (n-1)/n.

Answer (score 0):

How did you get average time 30 mins?
$$60\times 30 \% + 60 \times 30\% \times A + 60 \times 30\% \times B = 18+18 \times(A+B)=36$$

Should be 36 mins.